# What are the effects of changing the default page in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I am new to Google Analytics and need to make a change, we are adding site search. I can't save the site search change because GA has some incorrect info in it and will not let me save any changes. Specifically, the default page can't have slashes. So, when I try to save my other change, I get this error.

[image: characters not allowed]

It seems to me that the info that we have now is incorrect and isn't being used by Google.

I am pretty confident that if I remove the "avcat/ctl1642/index.cfm" from the default page I will be able to save it. I am not sure of what effect this will have on reporting, but I will never be able to re-enter that value if it isn't correct.

What are the effects of removing this bit of info? Should I just leave it blank? Shoud I just use index.cfm

Here is the current information that is saved.

[image: current info]

Answer (score 2):

The default page is the page that is displayed when a directory name is entered without a filename. For example: A user types mydomain.com/mydirectory/ into the browsers adress bar and the server serves the page mydomain.com/mydirectory/index.html. The exact name of the default page depends on the server configuration (usually it's along the lines of index.html, index.php, index.aspx, default.aspx or similar).

However Google will count mydomain.com/mydirectory/ and  mydomain.com/mydirectory/index.html as two different pages, even though they display the same content. So you can enter the name of the default page in Google Analytics to make sure the page count for both urls is aggregated into one value. The value for default page is applied to every url that ends with a trailing slash (and without a filename) since Google assumes that this is a directory name that displays the default page.

"vcat/ctl1642/index.cfm" does not make any sense as setting for a default page since it includes a directory path; a path is not a page. I'm amazed that it was ever possible to enter that value. If Google Analytics actually applied that value then all urls that ended with slash will be mangled (i.e. will have vcat/ctl1642/index.cfm added to them). Removing the value will mean that this does not happen anymore.